# Why doesn't this program end? The game goes on forever if i don't input the correct number

Tags: python

I am new to code and I was trying to create a guessing game as one of my first projects. I think i'm nearly done but this program doesn't end. Instead of ending when the there are 0 tries left it just continues the game even with the minus, Ps.(I made the number fixed for now, but will generate a random number when this issue is resolved)

I am new to code and I was trying to create a guessing game as one of my first projects. I think i'm nearly done but this program doesn't end. Instead of ending when the there are 0 tries left it just continues the game even with the minus, Ps.(I made the number fixed for now, but will generate a random number when this issue is resolved)

```
print("Welcome to my guessing game can you get the magic number hint, it's between 1 and 100 ")

Magic_number = 7
guess = int(input("Enter your guess:"))
guess_limit = 5
guess_counter = 1
out_of_guesses = False
print("You have", str(guess_limit - guess_counter), "tries left")

while guess != Magic_number and not out_of_guesses:
    while guess < Magic_number:
        print("That number is too small, try again")
        guess = int(input("Enter guess: "))
        guess_counter += 1
        print("You have", str(guess_limit - guess_counter), "tries left")

    while guess > Magic_number:
        print("That number is too high try again")
        guess = int(input("Enter guess: "))
        guess_counter += 1
        print("You have", str(guess_limit - guess_counter), "tries left")

    if guess == Magic_number:
        print("Well done you got it!!")

if out_of_guesses:
    print("Game over, sorry")
```

Comment: Notice how you have the lines `while guess < Magic_number:`, `while guess > Magic_number:`, `if guess == Magic_number:`? Is there a good reason to use `while` the first two times, and `if` the last time? No? Which one makes more sense for what you are doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not updating `out_of_guesses` wich means that your loop exit clause `while not out_of_guesses` is never triggered.

You are looping too much as well; your program is getting stuck in the inner while loops.

Try something like this:

```
print("Welcome to my guessing game can you get the magic number hint, it's between 1 and 100 ")

Magic_number = 7

guess_limit = 5
guess_counter = 0
out_of_guesses = False

print("You have", str(guess_limit - guess_counter), "tries left")

while not out_of_guesses:
    guess = int(input("Enter guess: "))

    if guess == Magic_number:
        print("Well done you got it!!")
        break

    elif guess < Magic_number:
        print("That number is too small, try again")

    elif guess > Magic_number:
        print("That number is too high try again")

    guess_counter += 1
    print("You have", str(guess_limit - guess_counter), "tries left")

    # exit clause
    if guess_limit == guess_counter:
        out_of_guesses = True
        print("Game over, sorry")
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to do `while guess > Magic_number:` or `while guess > Magic_number:`. You can directly use `if while guess > Magic_number:` and `if guess > Magic_number:` instead of them respectively and the program will still keep looping since there's an outer loop.

Your program isn't stopping because you have not checked the condition inside the **inner while loops** and therefore it keeps looping. The `guess_counter` will keep increasing inside the inner while loops but you have made no condition to break the loop on basis of `guess_counter`.

Just replace the inner while loops with if since you don't need them anyway. Hope this solves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

You did not update `out_of_guesses` variable, and you may use `if` and not `while` for the inner loops to avoid multiplying the place to check `out_of_guesses`. Then use a `break` if finds, that allows to put the code to run agin after it and not duplicate it

```
while not out_of_guesses:
    if guess < Magic_number:
        print("That number is too small, try again")
    elif guess > Magic_number:
        print("That number is too high try again")
    elif guess == Magic_number:
        print("Well done you got it!!")
        break

    guess = int(input("Enter guess: "))
    guess_counter += 1
    print("You have", str(guess_limit - guess_counter), "tries left")
    out_of_guesses = guess_counter>=guess_limit
```

Comment: When i wrote what you wrote if i didn't get the answer on the first try but got it on the second it would say this  : You have 6 tries left, Game Over!!!!
Well done you got it!!

Answer (score 0):

Few mistakes:

- The `while` loops inside the main loop should be `if` statements.
- The `out_of_guesses` was completely unused in your code

Tip:

- You may get out of a `while` (or `for`) loop using `break`

```py
print("Welcome to my guessing game can you get the magic number hint, it's between 1 and 100 ")

Magic_number = 7
guess_limit = 5
guess_counter = 1
guess = None

while guess != Magic_number:

    guesses_left = guess_limit - guess_counter + 1

    if guesses_left == 0:
        print("Game over, sorry")
        break

    print("You have", guesses_left, "tries left")
    guess = int(input("Enter guess: "))
    guess_counter += 1

    if guess < Magic_number:
        print("That number is too small, try again")

    elif guess > Magic_number:
        print("That number is too high try again")

    elif guess == Magic_number:
        print("Well done you got it!!")
        break
```